# UrlHighlight not working online server but working localhost

Tags: php

I want to use the https://github.com/vstelmakh/url-highlight plugin on Github. I'm doing everything right, I created the files on localhost. But while the same codes work correctly on localhost, it gives the following error on the online server.

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class
> 'VStelmakh\UrlHighlight\UrlHighlight' not found in
> /home1/****/public_html/includes/connect.php:4

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use VStelmakh\UrlHighlight\UrlHighlight;

$urlHighlight = new UrlHighlight();
echo $urlHighlight->highlightUrls('Hello, http://example.com.');
```

The same codes work fine on localhost. But if it does not work on the online server, what could be the reason for this.

Comment: have you ran "composer install" on the server? Uploading the vendor folder from localhost does not always work due to PHP version PHP modules not being the same.

Comment: Since there is no terminal in cPanel, I directly uploaded the installed files to the server.  However, I just realized that the same code works fine on another online server.